# Convert java cipher decrypt to python equivalent

Tags: java, python, encryption, rsa, x509

I'm trying to convert the below java code to python:

```
CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
serverCertificate = (X509Certificate) certFactory.generateCertificate(new FileInputStream(certFile));

Cipher decryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
decryptCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, serverCertificate.getPublicKey());
byte[] decryptedClientChallengeBytes = decryptCipher.doFinal(encryptedClientChallengeBytes);
```

The first part I think it's resolved with this:

```
from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend

cert = x509.load_pem_x509_certificate(key,default_backend())
cert = cert.public_key()
```

But I can't convert the decrypt part. I´ve tried various methods like PKCS1_v1_5.

I'm trying to implement this https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/marketing/responsys-rest-api/RequestUserAuthorization.html

And the step i'm stacked says: "You should receive the following response from the server. Decrypt (using the RSA algorithm) the encrypted clientChallenge using server certificate's public key (which you should have downloaded and stored on your system)."

The clientChallenge received is like this:

```
"hc8w8gElQJQa45WGofZwsOAi4wwEIaFClI1A2PvvCw4YUc4rbnOpedkBgrNsr0FpZ6DVV_vnZNsAGg_ph75VqeKD-R-cy_RkQIdvn0W_nb0RvPGZI7zA98_t9-rJTiTSsrJ6j8KzlWV_MLydUcBBR1iotL6kXXuFKuXtTAniPx_b6do4D5p9iI7yhTfxp9knRRG6XoItgNGJwm8AnGsThIoZw9lSgUm3Dy9yzYvhXQDYKAUNc3tqd8WcSswlb5coN18Gc-We2E0xE7xehq15Ns4QNwX6WdRrfehSgOObdckUYAx7MyLT-vyfJ-APVEVrZmC18wo-Qr2A-n1NT0ARVQ"
```

And the server certificate is a .CER with this format:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
.....
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: I don't think the cryptography.io library supports that unusual method of RSA signing. Reading those docs leaves me wondering about where the Responsys certificate comes from. If it's just the TLS certificate then that opens up a spectacular security hole, assuming my understanding is correct.

Comment: If you're doing decryption with the public key you're doing it incorrectly. Probably the only way is to raw decrypt and then unpad - probably using the signature padding scheme but without ASN.1 encoded hash identifier and hash value. They've got plenty of capable people at Oracle, I have no idea what went wrong here. Probably bought the company or something.